# Redirect to child record after creating it within a parent parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, activerecord, model

I have three models: `Stockholder` and `Folder`; each `Stock` has_many `Stockholders`, each `Stockholder` `has_one :folder`.  The `Folder` record is created within the `Stockholder` model like so.

```
before_create :build_default_folder
private
def build_default_folder
    logger.debug "The debug #{self.holder_index}"
    build_folder(name: "#{self.holder_index}. #{self.holder_name}", company_id: self.stock.company.id, parent_id: self.stock.company.folders.find_by_name("#{self.stock.security_series} #{self.stock.security_class} Stocks").id)
    true
end
```

Upon submission of the form in which information for stockholders are entered, I would like to redirect to the folder that was just created.  And am attempting to do so with the following redirect:

```
@stockholder=Stockholder.find(params[:id])
if @stockholder.update(stockholder_params)
  redirect_to company_browse_path(@stockholder.stock.company, @stockholder.folder.id)
end
```

This, however, results in the following error:

```
Undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

There is no issue, however, if the folder already exists and I'm simply editing the stockholder.  This leads me to believe that folder is not created in time for the controller to be able to use it as a parameter in the redirect.  How might I work around this?

Comment: What happens if you replace your redirect with `redirect_to @stockholder.folder` ?

Comment: @agustaf  Thanks for the response.  I get a `Cannot redirect to nil!`

Comment: Does the folder record actually get created?

Comment: @agustaf It does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, had to enter the redirect as follows:

```
redirect_to company_browse_path(@stockholder.stock.company, Folder.find_by(stockholder: @stockholder))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but it looks like there is some stuff missing. First, you need to associate the `Folder` with a `Stockholder`, the next thing is, your `Folder` needs to be saved. I don't know what `build_folder` does as I've never seen that before but here is what works for me:

```
before_create :build_default_folder

private
def build_default_folder
    folder = Folder.new(stockholder_id: self.id, name: "a name")
    folder.save
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above has the same result.